# Getting text values of li (without text in nested items)

Tags: jquery, dom, html-lists

```
<ul>
  <li class="item-i">AI</li>
  <li class="item-ii">AII
    <ul class="level-2">
      <li class="item-a">A</li>
      <li class="item-b">B</li>
      <li class="item-c">C</li>
    </ul>
  </li>
  <li class="item-iii">III</li>
</ul>
```

How can I get values `AI AII A B C III`?

What I tried so far is following:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('li').each(function(index) {
     alert($(this).text());
    });
});
```

But it does not gave me required results. When it reaches "item-ii" it gave all result.

I want item one by one.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
$(function(){
  var text = $('li').map(function(){
    return $(this).contents().map(function(){
      return this.nodeType==3 ? this.nodeValue : "";
    }).get().join('');
  }).get().join(' ');
  console.log(text);
  // AI AII
  //
  //     A B C III
});
```

The [`contents()`](http://api.jquery.com/contents/) method gives you both text nodes and child nodes. Text nodes have a `nodeType` of `3`. For less "functional"-style code, try this:

```
$(function(){
  $('li').each(function(){
    $(this).contents().each(function(){
      if (this.nodeType==3){
        console.log(this.nodeValue.replace(/^\s+|\s+$/g,''));
      }
    });
  });
  // AI
  // AII
  // 
  // A
  // B
  // C
  // III
});
```

Note that there is still a blank text node due to the markup.

Answer (score 2):

text() function selects all the nodes within the  list-itme 'item-ii' . Since you need to select only the text nodes, use this instead:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
            $('li').each(function(index) {
     alert($(this).contents().filter(function(){ return this.nodeType==3}).text());
    });
        });
```

Comment: Can we use the same line of code to update the text ?

Answer (score 1):

```
$(function() {
  var content = $.map($('ul li').contents(), function(elem, i) {
    if( elem.nodeType === 3 && $.trim(elem.nodeValue).length )
        return $.trim(elem.nodeValue);
  });

  alert(content);
});
```

Ref.: [$.map()](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.map/), [$.trim()](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.trim/), [.contents()](http://api.jquery.com/contents/)

Answer (score -2):

```
<form>
    <ul>    
     <li class="item-i">AI</li>
     <li class="item-ii">AII</li>
     <ul class="level-2">
         <li class="item-a">A</li>
         <li class="item-b">B</li>
         <li class="item-c">C</li>
        </ul>
      <li class="item-iii">III</li>
  </ul>
</form>
```

Comment: Try this code im getting alerts  AI AII A B C III respectively!

Comment: Separate from your formatting problems, this is illegal HTML. The HTML of the original question is syntactically valid; yours is not.